# Using device fonts and embedded fonts (FontAwesome) in the same TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, air, font-awesome-5

I have a TextField of type "input" and I want users to type in with "Arial"  and insert "FontAwesome 5" icons.
The users would be inserting icons through the software.
However to get the Icons to work I need to embed the `FontAwesome 5 Icons`

I do that using

```
[Embed(source="../assets/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf", fontName="Font Awesome 5 Free Solid", mimeType="application/x-font-opentype", embedAsCFF="false", unicodeRange="U+F000-F8FF")]
        private var asset:Class;
```

then in my code i register the font and enable embedded fonts for the text field.

```
        Font.registerFont(asset);
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.embedFonts = true;
            tf.type = "input";
            tf.mouseEnabled = true;
            tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 30, 0x000000, false, false, false, "", "", "left", 5, 5, 0, 0);
            tf.selectable = true;


        tf.appendText("Hello World!");
        
        
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Font Awesome 5 Free Solid";
        format.size = 30;
        format.color = 0xFF0000;
        tf.appendText(String.fromCharCode(0xf598));
        tf.setTextFormat(format, tf.length - 1, tf.length);
```

However, I set the defaultTextFormat as "Arial" since I want the users to type in regular script.
I then append some text that should be formatted as Arial and after that set the FontAwesome format and then insert a unicode character in the TextField.

However I am unable to see the text that was formatted as "Arial" I can only see the FontAwesome Icon.
[image]

Any ideas as to whats going wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use either device fonts or embedded fonts within a single **TextField**, not both at the same time. This is controlled by the **TextField.embedFonts** property: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#embedFonts

Comment: can I set embed fonts dynamically that is set it true when using FontAwesome and false when using Arial

Comment: Sure, you can. As long as you are not expecting your **TextField** to display embedded and non-embedded fonts at the same time, you are free to change that **TextField**'s behavior at any given moment.

Comment: @Organis I meant I will make "embedFonts = false" then append the "Arial" font text and then make " embedFonts = true" and then append the "Fontawesome" text. Will this retain both texts in the TextField?

Comment: You cannot display embedded and non-embedded fonts in the same **TextField** at the same time. It is irrelevant how do you add them, in which order, etc. If you set **embedFonts** to **true**, only embedded fonts will be displayed. Likewise, if you set **embedFonts** to **false**, only device fonts will be displayed.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks for the explanation. I tried using html text + unicode characters for FontAwesome but it doesn't display the characters  correctly, I guess we need to embed the font due to some limitation of the air runtime? Are you aware of any workaround for this? I mean showing unicode characters  in range 0XF000 to 0xF8FF?

Comment: Probably, this: https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate/embedding-unicode-characters/td-p/2416741?page=1

Comment: Please put in your first comment as an answer as I can mark it as selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either device fonts or embedded fonts within a single **TextField**, not both at the same time. This is controlled by the [TextField.embedFonts](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#embedFonts) property.